# notification saying Google play services has stoped working

Tags: applications

For my Samsung galaxy s2 there is a message saying Google paly services has stoped working it is really annoying and can you please fix it.

Comment: I had that problem when my G Apps wasn't installed properly. If you are on a custom rom and did you flash the gapps successfully? If not have you tried to factory reset?

Answer (score 0):

Once solution is to go into **applications** and disable Google play services. But u won't be able to use some apps such as Google photos.